# Isolating vibrations originating from my machine

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering, stresses, dynamics

I'm developing a machine with a reciprocating motion (mass: 50-100 kg, period: 1.35 s, accelerations: 1 g). This machine is part of a process line, and I don't want the resulting "shaking" to interfere with other machines. How do I go about doing this? A very stiff frame is an option, but a more elegant solution is preferable. Basically I'm building a frame around the reciprocating motion, and I have to connect that frame to the process line.

Comment: Fit a counter-balance?

Comment: A  picture would be helpful.  Some idea of the scale too.  Most systems like this would use isolated cells for each part of the process, each firmly anchored. The transfer components (conveyor belts, lines, etc) are not normally rigidly attached to the cells. In this way vibrations and other loads are not transferred.

Comment: Another option is a drastically heavier frame. I operated a CNC machine which, for extra rigidity and damping of vibrations, had its frame and table base cast from [terrazzo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terrazzo). The whole thing weigh well in excess of 5 tons with roughly 2/3 of that being in the terazzo frame. Looked a bit like a fancy grave with a tombstone too.

Answer (score 1):

The most elegant, but sometimes impractical solution, is a tuned mass damper. There are excellent [video resources](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=f1U4SAgy60c) available to discuss this concept, but the basic idea is that instead of attempting to stressfully contain vibrations, you cause a single part to move significantly.

This single mass on a spring, attached to the moving component, can cause the vibrations to come to a practical standstill. It works well in systems where the driving frequency is well known and the resonance of the first system is also known. An experienced mechanical engineer can usually design such a system to handle this method.

The less elegant, more practical approach is to reduce the stiffness of the parts attached to the vibrating component. These vibration isolator will then allow the vibrating component to vibrate, without causing the rest of the building to vibrate.  These systems are well known and have more availability to unknown frequencies and unknown natural frequencies, but can cause unwanted vibrations nevertheless.